# component of diff. function is also linear operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable function, i.e. $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),\dots, f_m(\mathbf{x}))$ where $f_i$ real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By definition we regard $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{x})$ as linear tranformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. How to prove strictly that each $f'_j(\mathbf{x})$ is linear tranformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Unfortunately I can't prove it. Can anyone show the correct proof?

Comment: Can you show that $f'_j(\mathbf x) = [\mathbf f'(\mathbf x)]_j$, i.e. that the derivative of the $j$th component is equal to the $j$th component of the derivative of $\mathbf f$? If you can show this, then $f_j'(\mathbf x) = P_j \circ {\mathbf f}'(\mathbf x)$ is a composition of the linear operator $P_j$, the projection onto the $j$th component and the derivative.

Comment: @Roland, No I can't show this. I also thinking about this but I tried and have no results.

Comment: @Roland, Can you show the full proof please? I would be very thankful for your help!

Comment: If I'd know how to show the identity in my comment, I would have posted it as an answer if I'd had the proof laid out in my mind. It's possible that this is just as hard as your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

mMaybe I didn't get your question well but since $f_j(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for definition $f'_j(x)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (you gave the definition, just use $m=1$).
On the other side you may be asking why,since $f$ is differentiable, also $f_j$ is. This is because the matrix representing $f'$ is of the type $$ \begin{pmatrix} f'_1(x) \\f'_2(x)\\...\\f'_m(x)  \end{pmatrix}$$ and everyone of the $f'_j(x) $"approximates" (accordingly to the definition of differential) $f_j(x)$ well .

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence more detailed?

Comment: I am interested in the following. If $f$ is differentiable  why $f_j$ also differentiable?

Comment: Check the definition of differentiable. You'll see you have a limit to prove. In this limit you have all the components of f, that are the $f_j$, converging to a certain value (because if a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ converges then all its components do). The convergence of the components is exactly the convergence of the  $f_j$ when you're looking for their differential.